# ASP.NET MVC Passing innerHTML text of spans within a div to the controller

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm currently trying to get the strings from the spans and store them in a javascript string variable. Next I'm trying to pass the data when I click on the search button which is a HTML.ActionLink.
For simplicity, I added only the relevant bits of code.

This is the code inside my view:
This is the javascript part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#search', function () {
        var tags = '';
        var spans = document.getElementById('imaginary_container').getElementsByTagName('span'),
        obj = {};

        for (var i = 0, l = spans.length; i < l; i++) {
            obj[spans[i].id] = spans[i].textContent || spans[i].innerText;
            tags.concat(obj[spans[i].id]);
        }

        // save private tags

    })
});
```

Then I have this div below where I have the button:

```
<div class="buttonBox">
            @Html.ActionLink("Search",
                "SearchAll",
                "Search",
                new { tags = ViewBag.Tags },
                new
                {
                    @class = "btn btn-primary",

                }
                )
        </div>

    </div>
```

I have researched this issue and people say it's either impossible or there are outdated answers. If however I'm going in the wrong direction, could someone please point the way to making this happen?

More context:
The application displays tags on the front page which you can click and move to another div as a span, I need the data of the selected tags to be sent back as string so I can query a response on another page displays files and links which link to these tags.

[Front Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92xzV.png)

Update:

I've added a form with a post action and a hidden input where I store the 
values of the spans.

The javascript function that deals with the reposition of the tags now also
adds the innerText of the spans to my hidden input.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).on('click', '.delete-button', function () {

            var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
            document.getElementById('imaginary_container').appendChild(newSpan);
            newSpan.innerHTML = $(this).html();
            var tags = $("#tags");
            var tags = "";
            var spans = document.getElementById('imaginary_container').getElementsByTagName('span'),
            obj = {};
            tags += spans[0].innerText;
            for (var i = 1, l = spans.length; i < l; i++) {
                tags += ',' + spans[i].innerText;
            }

            $("#tags").val(tags);

            $(this).remove();
        })
    });
```

and a simple hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="tags" name="Tags" />
```

This works just fine now!

Comment: Are you trying to make a listbox like [this](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/listbox) or [this](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/listbox/drag-and-drop)?

Comment: I've added an image with the design of the front page, if it helps, the image can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/92xzV.png

Comment: You either need a `<form>` that makes a GET, and you will have a `<input type="hidden" name="tags" value="yourTagName" />` that gets moved into the form when you drag and drop, which will post back to a method with a `string[] tags` parameter. Or you need to build the url (to look like `/Search/SearchAll?tags=someTag&tags=anotherTag&tags=.....` etc (and you can make use of the [$.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) to help with that)

Comment: Thank you @StephenMuecke, I have tried the first method, I've made a form with a post action and within the form I have a hidden input (note that it's not required to be moved at the tags repositioning) and I'm appending the values to the hidden input with my tags moving javascript function.